# lvalue required as left operand of assignment - What causes this error and how to fix it?

Tags: c, char, c-strings, implicit-conversion, function-definition

Here is the piece of code. Its in C, compiler is CodeBlocks
I made a function Replacethings which is supposed to replace all characters that are spaces, commas, and exclamation points with *. Seemingly an easy task, and yet so hard. The input has to be 25 characters or less.

```
void Replacethings( char *StrongOfChars[25]){
 for(int i =0; i<25; i++){

    if(*StrongOfChars[i]=' ' || *StrongOfChars[i] = ',' || *StrongOfChars[i] = '!'){
        *StrongOfChars[i]= '*';
        printf("%c", StrongOfChars[i]);
    }

 }
} 
printf("Enter your favorite quote (Has to be less than 25 characters)!");
    char StronKK[25];

    scanf("%s", &StronKK);
    Replacethings(&StronKK);
    printf("\n Your favorite squote is now: %s +", StronKK);
```

Comment: Do you know that `char *StrongOfChars[25]` is an array of pointers, not characters? And having passed *one* string, the loop must be the actual elements used by the string, not the unused elements. Take out every `*` (except `'*'`).

Comment: Also you have typos where `=` in the three comparisons should be `==`.

Comment: Make it a habit to raise the warning level of your compiler to the maximum and correct your code until no errors and no warnings.

Comment: `char StronKK[25];` is one-too-small to handle "input has to be 25 characters ...".

Answer (score 0):

`*StrongOfChars[i]=' '` means you assign the value ' ' to the first character of the i'th char pointer:

```
    if(*StrongOfChars[i]=' ' || *StrongOfChars[i] = ',' || *StrongOfChars[i] = '!'){
```

You want to use `==` instead.  The first expression of the body of the `if` statement is:

```
*StrongOfChars[i]= '*';
```

which probably should be part of your if expression instead, i.e.:

```
if(
   *StrongOfChars[i] == ' ' ||
   *StrongOfChars[i] == ',' ||
   *StrongOfChars[i] == '!' ||
   *StrongOfChars[i] == '*'
) {
   ...
}
```

or you can use `strchr(" ,!*", *StrongOfChars[i])` instead of those 4 conditions.

The code is poorly formatted, so you cannot see that the `}` before the 2nd print statement is in the wrong place so the print statement is not in a function.  Maybe remove it or you forgot a `main()` function?

Answer (score 0):

As you declared the array `StronKK` like

```
char StronKK[25];
```

then the expression `&StronKK` has the type `char ( * )[25]`.

So you have to write in the call of `scanf`

```
scanf( "%24s", StronKK );
```

On the other hand, the function parameter has the type `char *StrongOfChars[25]`

```
void Replacethings( char *StrongOfChars[25])
```

that is adjusted by the compiler to the type `char **`

```
void Replacethings( char **StrongOfChars )
```

The types `char ( * )[25]` and `char **` are not compatible types and the compiler should issue a diagnostic message.

You need to declare the function like

```
void Replacethings( char *StrongOfChars )
```

or

```
void Replacethings( char StrongOfChars[25])
```

or

```
void Replacethings( char StrongOfChars[])
```

and call it like

```
Replacethings( StronKK );
```

Pay attention to that the user can enter a string with the length less than `25`. So using the magic number `25` within the function is a bad idea and can result in undefined behavior.

Also instead of the equality operator `==` you are using the assignment operator `=` within the for loop of the function.

The function can be defined the following way

```
void Replacethings( char StrongOfChars[])
{
    for ( ; *StrongOfChars != '\0'; ++StrongOfChars )
    {
        if ( *StrongOfChars == ' ' || 
             *StrongOfChars == ',' || 
             *StrongOfChars == '!' )
        {
            *StrongOfChars = '*';
        }
    }
}
```

It would be also reasonable to check whether a character is a tab character. That is the if statement can look

```
        if ( *StrongOfChars == ' ' || 
             *StrongOfChars == '\t' || 
             *StrongOfChars == ',' || 
             *StrongOfChars == '!' )
        {
            *StrongOfChars = '*';
        }
```

Or you can write it lime

```
if ( strchr( " \t,!", *StrongOfChars ) )
{
    *StrongOfChars = '*';
}
```

To use the function `strchr` you need to include header `<string.h>`.